# Converting Bezier to NURBS Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, conversion, nurbs-surface

I was trying to convert a Bezier curve to a NURBS curve by clicking Curve->Set Spline Type->NURBS. But after the conversion to NURBS, the curve disappears. Is there any way to preserve the original shape of the Bezier after making it a NURBS curve?

Answer (score 1):

Check Handles in the operator panel to transform handles too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If your mesh is not yet a curve, first go to `Object -> Convert -> Curve`.
2. Once you have your curve, you can switch to different types by going to `Curve -> Set Spline Type -> NURBS` (or whatever type you want).

Example:

[image]

Blender 3.3